# How to Upload a multipage PDF and convert each page to a JPEG with Paperclip?

Tags: ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, docsplit

Does anyone know how to upload a multi-page pdf with Paperclip and convert each page into a Jpeg?

So far, every time I upload a PDF, it only allows me to see the first page of the PDF as a JPEG. But I would like to be able to upload and convert every page from the PDF into a JPEG.

Is there any gem or plug-in that can help me upload a 10-pg PDF and Convert/Store it in the Database as 10 JPEG files?

I have looked at [docsplit-images](https://github.com/jameshuynh/docsplit_images) gem, but I am not sure if that is the best solution or how it works.

Post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Blogs

  attr_accessible :content, :title, :pdf

  has_attached_file :pdf,
                    :url  => "/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

  validates_attachment_content_type :pdf,
      :content_type => [ 'application/pdf' ],
      :message => "only pdf files are allowed"
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for ([@post]), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

    <%= f.file_field :pdf %>

<% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
  <%= image_tag @post.pdf.url(:original) %>
```